# Number of ways to write a natural as a sum of naturals

Tags: induction, natural-numbers

**Problem:**

Let $n$ be a natural number, and $S(n)$ be the number of ways $n$ can be written as a sum of naturals.

For instance, $S(3) = 4$ because $3 = 2+1 = 1+2 = 1+1+1$ and these are four different ways.

Note that we count single-term sums, and different permutations.

Find and prove a simple formula for $S(n)$.

**My attempts** so far has been to try and do this with induction. By testing the first four cases, I have found that the pattern seems to be that $S(n) = 2^{n-1}$ but I'm unable to prove it.

I am open to other ways of doing this besides induction, of course. It just came to mind because of evaluation on naturals only.

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827536

Comment: Thanks. It didn't show up in my searches because of wording, but I can see why you would be able to find it :)

Comment: Although it is technically the same question as the one I linked to, this version is written much better.

Comment: Many Questions are about this, for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507413/proof-for-number-of-weak-compositions).  Of course it helps to know the technical term for such sums is *compositions*.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 - Hehe, thanks. Your answer also provided a method for solution with which I'm already familiar, so it immediately simplified the problem for me. Not to detract from the help of other answerers in this question, of course.

Comment: @hardmath - Thanks! Was not aware of the terminology.

Answer (score 3):

We consider a case where the number $n$ is expressed as a sum of $m$ natural numbers. The number of ways to do so is given by the coefficient of $x^n$ in
$$(x+x^2+x^3+...)^m$$
To illustrate this point, we look at a specific example, with n=4 and m=2. The expression is 
$$(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...)(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...)$$
There are $3$ ways to form $x^4$ in the above expression
$$x^{1+3}=x^4$$
$$x^{2+2}=x^4$$
$$x^{3+1}=x^4$$
and you can see that the coefficient of $x^4$ is indeed the number of ways to express $4$ as a sum of $2$ natural numbers.

 Since $1\le m\le n$,
$$S(n)=\sum^{n}_{m=1}[x^n](x+x^2+...)^m=\sum^{n}_{m=1}[x^{n-m}](1-x)^{-m}=\sum^{n}_{m=1}\binom{m+n-m-1}{n-m}=2^{n-1}$$
by the Binomial Theorem

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is ordered tuples $(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$, $k=1,\ldots,n$ with $a_i>0$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k a_i=n$. Now, an ordered tuple $(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$ with $a_i>0$ such that the sum is $=n$ is just a set of $k$ boxes with at least one ball inside, i.e. $n-k$ balls in $k$ boxes. This is known to equal $$\binom{n-k+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$ so summing throughout gives $$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

which is...?